# Multi-variable function: Limit and continuity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm having trouble solving this calculus assignment.

Let $H(x)=\lim_{y \to0}h(x,y)$ where $h(x,y)=\frac{\cos x-\cos y}{2(x^2+y^2)}$

I've found that $H(x)=\lim_{y \to0}h(x,y)$ is $\frac{cos(x) - 1}{2x^2}, x\neq 0$

and

$\lim_{x \to0}\frac{cos(x) - 1}{2x^2}$ is $-\frac{1}{4}$

Now I'm having trouble determining whether $H$ is a continuous function of $x$, and what that says about the ability to find a value $c=h(0,0)$ such that $h$ becomes continous in the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: So you've tried one path. Can you find another such that the limits are not equal? The would be sufficient to indicate the function is not continuous. If not, prove it from the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition.

Comment: We have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} h(x,y) = \frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}
$$
and $$
\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^2} = \frac12.
$$
From here can you conclude?